# Why Android JNI code has different result than adb shell with the same command?

Tags: android

I am trying to get Android network stats using the code below:

```
string cmd = "cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats";
string info = Utils::exec(cmd);
```

It returns only `headers` of the information table, like:

```
idx iface acct_tag_hex uid_tag_int cnt_set rx_bytes rx_packets tx_bytes tx_packets rx_tcp_bytes rx_tcp_packets rx_udp_bytes rx_udp_packets rx_other_bytes rx_other_packets tx_tcp_bytes tx_tcp_packets tx_udp_bytes tx_udp_packets tx_other_bytes tx_other_packets
```

But when I execute this command via `adb shell cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats`, the result sames fine.

How can I deal with this issue? Do I need to root my phone?

### EDIT

`adb shell id`'s output:

`uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0`

Comment: yes, you need the root access

Comment: @pskink But I can using `adb shell` to obtain those data without root my phone.

Comment: whats the output of: `adb shell id` ?

Comment: @pskink Updated my question